How to design how to slope a French drain around perimeter of the house and how to measure depth?
I am planning to DIY a French drain around parts of my 1920ies stucco house to improve the draining when it heavily rains in winter.
Location is San Francisco Bay Area and the house has a crawl space.
I have roughly 95 ft to cover, on the backside of the house (deck), the side of the house (mostly pavers currently but I need to regrade those anyway) and parts of the front. In this picture the, the blue line denotes the planned French drain (right next to the concrete foundation).

There is also an existing drain cover which ideally I'd run it to (indicated in the red box).
Ideally, I'd like to slope it all the way to the front so the drain has a natural decline all the way to the drain.

When planning, how to I determine the best path/decline?
When planning, how to I determine the required depth at each location?
When actually building, how do I know that is the actual depth and how deep I need to dig? The problem is that I do not have an accurate reference point. The ground itself can easily be up and down a few inches just on the side of the house


Are you planning to excavate down to the foundation, or will this french drain be near the surface?

I will edit the post accordingly: It’s a Bay Area house with crawl space. In other words, the foundation isn’t too deep and the upper part sticks out to ground level. I was thinking next to the foundation but as shallow as it could be.

Stakes and a level come to mind. Then a set of shims to set the height per distance based on the slope you need. If a quality level (laser or bubble) is out of budget then a clear tube with water in also works...

Do you have any siding, or anything that should be horizontal, on your house?  Fascia boards?

I second @SolarMike, an easy and cheap method is to use a clear tube with water in it. You can directly measure the height change one the distance by lowering the pipe relative to the water other at the far end.

@Huesmann, no, it's just stucco into floor whose leveling I currently do not trust.

@SolarMike The clear pipe is a great idea! Do you have a reference for "Stakes and a level come to mind. Then a set of shims to set the height per distance based on the slope you need."? Possibly with pictures? I have a hard time imagining what you mean. I mean, making a localized straight line sounds straight forward (with the bubble level). But how to accurately measure relative distance from ground between two points 80 ft apart?

@divB well, you could be simple and just make marks every 2 , 3 or 5 feet on the building - they make that marker spray paint for exactly that. If not there are long tape measures available or the wheel distance devices used by surveyors - should be simple enough to use.

@divB you would basically need to walk your level line along the house, using whatever the longest method you can.  Set an elevation at Point A, use your 6' level to set the same elevation at Point B 6' away, use Point B to set the elevation at Point C, which is 12' away from Point A, etc.  Unfortunately, that method leaves some room for error to creep in, as it depends on your level being 100% accurate (both in the instrument or the user).  If you can buy/borrow a laser level, that might be more accurate.
